# TypeScript to add methods?

Tags: typescript

I'm just learning TypeScript and getting stuck trying to add some methods to the DOM or other existing objects. As an example, I'm trying to add a method I can call to use color in console logging. However, I'm getting a couple of TypeScript errors.

```
Object.defineProperties(console, {
    redLog: function(msg: string) { console.log(`%c${msg}`, 'color:red'); //TS error: Type '(msg: string) => void' has no properties in common with type 'PropertyDescriptor'.
    },
});

console.redLog("This should print red") //TS error: Property 'redLog' does not exist on type 'Console'.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm not sure how to leverage interfaces or whatever TS approach would be needed to allow me to add this console.redLog() method. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

When modifying objects that are already defined in TypeScript, you need two things:

- definition
- implementation (that you've done)

To tell TypeScript it can expect a method called `redLog` on the `console`, you need to find the type/interface that stores the definition of `console` and *augment* it.

In this case, `console` is described by the `Console` interface defined in the global scope. To add a property to that interface, you need to enter the scope in which it exists and define it again. Your definition will be merged with the existing one.

This definition will enter the global scope (`declare global`) and re-define the `Console` interface:

```
declare global {
  interface Console {
    redLog(msg: string): string;
  }
}
```

Put that definition in your project, and your global `Console` will be augmented!

**Complete solution**

```
declare global {
  interface Console {
    redLog(msg: string): void;
  }
}

Object.defineProperties(console, {
  redLog: {
    value: function (msg: string) {
      console.log(`%c${msg}`, 'color:red')
    },
  }
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=22&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgMIrEDOKECeBBcwAMiogAoAtk0QAueE1IwSiAJQSAbikLAA3PngBfXDtwgAHgAcUMUjm25cYRizYA6bn0TwAvPEoBXYmFKFG8MKiElIyxPIWNsysIPaogtjwIi5aADTwAOQ2qDBi3BlyatrpAPQlAOqmANZMVgDyaABW4KT2oJQkIAAKMChGFKQAngJRdiDpHPBO-BJePn4BQeKS0rJyOJoEAAYApGAAJNjJWlvpWaymeSDAGZo6WnJWBA3Nvm0gHcTdvf1mhCBMEa2GITTZTa7OWbeXz%20YiBZIhVbhdaTTjwUYxOL8AS7A5HUQnM7ZS75R5otJ3Qq4IA)

Comment: Thank you! I made a small tweak to expect a void for the return and am able to directly add the method.

However, I still get the same TypeScript error when I try to add it via Object.defineProperties(). Could you help me understand what I'm missing there?

declare global {
 interface Console {
  redLog(msg: string): void;
 }
}

console.redLog = function (msg: string) { console.log(`%c${msg}`, 'color:red'); }, //Works

Object.defineProperties(console, {
 redLog: function (msg: string) {
  console.log(`%c${msg}`, 'color:red'); //same TS error
 },
});

Comment: Of course! Sorry for not having verified this myself. When using `Object.defineProperties`, you need to define your newly added property in a special way. The object on the right-hand side must conform to the `PropertyDescriptor` interface. In other words, you need a nested property called `value` which should point to your implementation. I updated my answer.